# My form isn't showing the error message correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, modal-dialog

I built an online form and published it here --> https://www.worthit.cc/

It has a built-in error that's suppose to fire whenever the submit button is clicked and any of the fields are empty. However, it doesn't always show like it's supposed to.

Here's the link to the full code on GitHub: https://github.com/ZacharyFoxLuke/Worth-It

And here's the JS in question:

```js
$modal = $('.modal-frame')
$modal_Rewards_Info = $('#inputFields #rewards-info-message')
$modal_Transaction_Fee = $('#inputFields #transactionFee-info-message')
$modal_Profit = $('#profit-message')
$modal_Loss = $('#loss-message')
$modal_BreakEven = $('#break-even-message')
$modal_Error = $('#error-message')
$modal_About = $('#about-message')
$modal_Contact = $('#contact-message')
$submitButton = $('#submitButton')
$dollarsProfit = $('.dollarsProfit')
$dollarsFee = $('.dollarsFee')
$dollarsNet = $('.dollarsNet')

$submitButton.click(function () {
    const purchaseAmount = document.getElementById('purchaseAmountInput').value
    const rewardsRate = document.getElementById('rewardsRateInput').value / 100
    const transactionFeeInput = document.getElementById('variFeeInput').value / 100
    const transactionFeeNet = purchaseAmount * transactionFeeInput
    const earnedRewards = purchaseAmount * rewardsRate
    
    if (purchaseAmount === '' || rewardsRate === '' || transactionFeeInput === '') {
        $modal_Error.toggleClass('active')
        $modal_Error.removeClass('leave')

    } else if (rewardsRate === transactionFeeInput && rewardsRate !== '' && transactionFeeInput !== '' && purchaseAmount !== '') {
        $modal_BreakEven.toggleClass('active')
        $modal_BreakEven.removeClass('leave')
        $dollarsProfit.html(rewardsRate * purchaseAmount)
        $dollarsFee.html(transactionFeeNet)

    } else if (rewardsRate < transactionFeeInput && rewardsRate !== '' && transactionFeeInput !== '' && purchaseAmount !== '') {
        $modal_Loss.toggleClass('active')
        $modal_Loss.removeClass('leave')
        $dollarsProfit.html(rewardsRate * purchaseAmount)
        $dollarsFee.html(transactionFeeNet)
        $dollarsNet.html(earnedRewards - transactionFeeNet)

    } else if (rewardsRate > transactionFeeInput && rewardsRate !== '' && transactionFeeInput !== '' && purchaseAmount !== '') {
        $modal_Profit.toggleClass('active')
        $modal_Profit.removeClass('leave')
        $dollarsProfit.html(rewardsRate * purchaseAmount)
        $dollarsFee.html(transactionFeeNet)
        $dollarsNet.html(earnedRewards - transactionFeeNet)

    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you may add a function to check whether the amount is actually a valid amount and manipulate your code a little more using this function.

```js
checkTheAmount = (item) => {
  if (item && parseFloat(item) > 0) return true;
  return false;
};
```

```
checkTheAmount = (item) => {
  if (item && parseFloat(item) > 0) return True;
  return False;
};

$submitButton.click(function () {
  const purchaseAmount = document.getElementById("purchaseAmountInput").value;
  const rewardsRate = document.getElementById("rewardsRateInput").value / 100;
  const transactionFeeInput =
    document.getElementById("variFeeInput").value / 100;
  const transactionFeeNet = purchaseAmount * transactionFeeInput;
  const earnedRewards = purchaseAmount * rewardsRate;

  if (
    checkTheAmount(purchaseAmount) == false ||
    checkTheAmount(rewardsRate) == false ||
    checkTheAmount(transactionFeeInput) == false
    
  ) {
    $modal_Error.toggleClass("active");
    $modal_Error.removeClass("leave");
  } else if (
    rewardsRate === transactionFeeInput &&
    rewardsRate !== "" &&
    transactionFeeInput !== "" &&
    purchaseAmount !== ""
  ) {
    $modal_BreakEven.toggleClass("active");
    $modal_BreakEven.removeClass("leave");
    $dollarsProfit.html(rewardsRate * purchaseAmount);
    $dollarsFee.html(transactionFeeNet);
  } else if (
    rewardsRate < transactionFeeInput &&
    rewardsRate !== "" &&
    transactionFeeInput !== "" &&
    purchaseAmount !== ""
  ) {
    $modal_Loss.toggleClass("active");
    $modal_Loss.removeClass("leave");
    $dollarsProfit.html(rewardsRate * purchaseAmount);
    $dollarsFee.html(transactionFeeNet);
    $dollarsNet.html(earnedRewards - transactionFeeNet);
  } else if (
    rewardsRate > transactionFeeInput &&
    rewardsRate !== "" &&
    transactionFeeInput !== "" &&
    purchaseAmount !== ""
  ) {
    $modal_Profit.toggleClass("active");
    $modal_Profit.removeClass("leave");
    $dollarsProfit.html(rewardsRate * purchaseAmount);
    $dollarsFee.html(transactionFeeNet);
    $dollarsNet.html(earnedRewards - transactionFeeNet);
  }
});
```